# Retrieve variable from $localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, local-storage, bootstrap-table

I'm working with [bootstrap table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) and ngStorage. What I'm trying to do is to save search to local storage and retrieve it back after table has been refreshed. 
This is my simple code:

js

```
 //Assigning $localstorage to $session.storage
        $scope.storage = $localStorage;
        $scope.saveSearch = function () {
            $scope.child = prompt('Set your filter.');

            $('#table').on('search.bs.table', function (e, text){
                $scope.storage = text
            });

        };
        $scope.loadSearch = function() {

            $scope.data = $scope.storage;

        };
```

html

```
<div id="toolbar">
<div style="display: -webkit-box">
<button id="new" class="btn btn-default">New</button>
<button id="edit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
<button id="remove" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
<button class="btn btn-default " ng-click="saveSearch()">Save Filter</button>
<button class="btn btn-default " ng-click = "loadSearch()">Load Filter</button>
<button id="button" class="btn-primary btn">Load Table</button>
<pre>{{data}}</pre></div>
</div>
table id="table"
      class="table-striped"
                        data-toggle="table"
                        data-toolbar="#toolbar"
                        data-search="true"
                        data-show-columns="true"
                        data-show-export="true"
                        data-filter-control="true"
                        data-events="operateEvents"
                        data-formatter="operateFormatter"
                        data-response-handler="responseHandler"
                        >
                        </table>
```

and thru this code I'm getting variable back, when I click on button Load Filter. You can see that on the right side of Load Table button.

[image]

But when I'm trying to push this variable to search.

```
  $scope.loadSearch = function() {
            $('#table').on('search.bs.table', function (e, text){
                text.push($scope.storage);
                console.log($scope.storage)
            });
            $scope.data = $scope.storage;
        };
```

My function doesn't work at all. I appreciate if anybody could explain me where is my mistake?

[**My plunker, where you can see the problem**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1ioHwjF2J1BPNWXYQFqM?p=preview)

[**With this plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/K21VaAiulWaVZN1ZtbDR?p=preview), you can put value from localstorage to search bs table, but it is not triggering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save text to local storage

```
$scope.storage.text = text;
```

and than to retrieve the text

```
$scope.data = $scope.storage.text
```

Comment: The text is retrieving, problem is I can't push back this text to search

Comment: did you try text.push($scope.storage.text);

Comment: If I'm using $scope.storage.text it gives me text is undefined

Comment: did you save text to storage.text?  you gotta save text to load it

Comment: And what do you mean code of my search? it is part of bs tables and thru this `text` inside this func `$('#table').on('search.bs.table', function (e, text){
            });` you can find search value

Comment: the html for the bs tables.  if you can add a jsfiddle with the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110664/discussion-between-anton-and-lun-zhang).

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.storage = $locastorage` assigns the whole `$localstorage` Object to the Variable. I don't think that this is what you want to do.

To read a specific Variable of `$localstorage` do

```
$scope.myvar = $localstorage.localvar
```

Furthermore `text.push($scope.storage);` doesn't assign anything to `$scope.storage`. `myarray.push(myvar)` adds `myvar` to `myarray`

To put something into `$scope.storage` do

- `$scope.storage = text`
- `$scope.storage.mykey = text`

Comment: It returns: `TypeError: $scope.storage.push is not a function`

Comment: Seems about right.
I did some reading: the $scope.storage = $localstorage pushes the whole local storage in this variable. Please try `$scope.storage = text`